# Android-How to secure my source code

Tags: android, api, security, decompiling

Assuming that i have an android client app that calls web services to get some data from a data base from the remote server, which means in some part of my code i will be using the URL of the backend to call the APIs i need , now probably there are android de-compilers now that get the source code of an APK file which means the URL that i use to call the API could be subjected to someone that de-compiles my application , which is a primary problem that i want to avoid even if i have secured my remote server with authentication whether it was basic or digest or what ever , i still don't want my URL of the API to be subjected to someone from the first place , how can i avoid this to happen, is there some kind algorithm that could decode my URL inside my code so when my APK would be de-compiled that the addresses of these APIs i call would not be exposed?

Comment: You could employ naive mechanisms that scramble / descramble the string so it won't look like an URL at first glance, but ofc that is easily reverse-engineered by anyone who wants to know the URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent an attacker from getting the URL. You should have some apikey or password, unique to each user, to prevent un-authorized access to your api.

Since the attacker has the apk, and since the app has to know what url to use, there has to be some logic in the apk that the attacker can just use to get the url, nomatter how fancy scheme of url-obfuscation you come up with.

Answer (score -2):

Your code can be reverse-engineered in nearly every case, even if you use Androids [built-in obfuscator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html). You only can make it harder for an attacker. So including an apikey or password does not work either - because this super-secret information also has to be stored somewhere.

But the big problem is: Monitoring the network traffic **will reveal the <strike>URL</strike> server's location in any case**, no matter what you do.

So the only solution is to design your server in a way that it can deal with "evil" requests. There is no way around it, otherwise your server can be hacked! So...

- you don't want anybody to know your server? **not possible**
- you want to limit the requests per user? **Nearly impossible**. If it where easy, Denial-of-Service attacks would be a thing of the past. Limiting the numbers of requests per IP address is a start but not flawless since mobile phones often change their address.

Comment: but you may be wrong about "Monitoring the network traffic will reveal the URL in any case" , if the connection was encrypted by SSL  for example then packet sniffers should not be able to show requests url

Comment: i'm assuming the traffic is sent over TLS, so the URL will not be revealed to sniffers, but it's there in the source

Comment: ok, the data is secure, but the server's address can be determined. I was assuming that everything should be kept secret. But if this is not the case, then my claim is indeed false. Thanks for the clarification